# Ensure that table cell widths are respected

Tags: html, css, html-table, tablelayout, word-wrap

I have a HTML `<table>` with multiple cols. How do I ensure that the given cell/col width is respected in any case? That is to say that if I give a cell a width of 100px and if the text content is long (exceeds 100 chars without any spaces), the text content should respect the 100px width and wrap to next line..

I have already tried using `word-wrap:break-word`, but that does not work.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `table-layout: fixed` to ensure your `td` widths are respected.

Check out the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/table-layout) for additional information.

**Edit**

Something like this should work for you:

```
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}
td {
    color:white;
    width:50px;
    background-color:Blue;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    max-width:50px;
}
```

Here's [a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesHill/52Ksg/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Ok...I had tried that...But that does not seem correctly to work for the case where I have a cell with very long text (without any space in between)....i.e. even though the cell width is respected, the text kind of overlaps and does not wrap to the next line..

Comment: Thx a lot...I just tried that...It is working fine in Firefox..But in IE8, I only see the 1st line of text content...The wrapped 2nd line is not shown at all..